# Outlook MailItem Save/SaveAs

Tags: c#, vb.net, outlook, outlook-addin, mailitem

I have an outlook add-in that allows the user to save an email into a database. When the user does save the email I modify the email subject so it can be identified as being saved.

Saving the email can happen in two ways. Via a button on the tool bar which allows the user to save any email they want, and also via a prompt which appears when a new email is put into the Sent Items folder. Both methods use the same form to save the email!

OK, now to the problem ....

In the process of saving the email I use the `mailItem.SaveAs` method to put it into the file store. After this has completed successfully i want to change the subject of the email which still exists in outlook to say that it has been saved successfully. I do this by changing `myItem.Subject` and then using the `mailItem.Save` method to save the change.

The above works perfectly when the email isn't being saved via the prompt method. So when the user tries to save the email after they send it the `mailItem.Save` method does not work.

I have narrowed it down to it actually working if i put the `myItem.Save()` line before the `myItem.SaveAs()` line, but obviously if I do this I can not guarantee the email was actually saved properly.

So does any one know of a reason that the `mailItem.Save` method would want to not work after the `mailItem.SaveAs` method as been called?

Thank you in advance to any suggestions to what might be the problem.

EDIT : Code

```
if (_item is Outlook.MailItem) { // if the incoming item is an Outlook mail Item
    // cast as a mail item
    Outlook.MailItem myItem = (Outlook.MailItem)_item;
    if (directoryExists(directoryTemp)) { // if the temporary directory exists
        bool _profiled = true;
        // copy the item as type .msg in the temporary location
        myItem.SaveAs(saveTemp, Outlook.OlSaveAsType.olMSG);
        // setup impersonation to copy the file to a secure location
        PImpersonateUser _iU = new PImpersonateUser();
        // do impersonation
        try {
            _iU.Impersonate("******", "******", "******");
            if (File.Exists(savefile)) { // if file already exists in the location
                // delete existing file
                File.Delete(savefile);
            }
            // move the temporary file to the secure location with the proper name
            File.Move(saveTemp, savefile);
            string year = "";
            if (ipt_year.SelectedItem != null) { // else if year has been selected
                year = ipt_year.SelectedItem.ToString();
            }
            _profile.profileEmail(folderString(_subject_), _fileName, year);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            _profiled = false;
            // if impersonation fails cancel the impersonation
            _iU.Undo();
            // show error
            MessageBox.Show(e.Source + "\n\n" + e.Message + "\n\n" + e.StackTrace, "SaveAs() Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        } finally {
            _iU.Undo();
        }
        if (_profiled) { // if the email was profiled successfully
            // mark the original email as being profiled
            markAsProfiled();
        }
    } else {
        // if temporary file save fails throw error
        MessageBox.Show("Temporary Directory (" + directoryTemp + ") Does Not Exist!", "Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

---

and the  markAsProfiled function ...

---

```
private void markAsProfiled() {
    if (_item is Outlook.MailItem) { // if the incoming item is an Outlook mail Item
        // cast as a mail item
        Outlook.MailItem myItem = (Outlook.MailItem)_item;
        // make sure subject doesnt already have a profiled flag in the subject
        _subject_ = _subject_.Replace("[PROFILED] - ", "");
        // add a profiled flag in the subject of the email
        myItem.Subject = "[PROFILED] - " + _subject_;
        // add a yellow flag to the email
        myItem.FlagIcon = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlFlagIcon.olYellowFlagIcon;
        // save email with changes made
        myItem.Save();
        //MessageBox.Show("Mark as Profiled :: " + myItem.Subject + " :: " + myItem.Saved.ToString() + " :: ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain in al ittel more detail your "prompt workflow". how are you hooking into the send etc. as there are a number of way to do this.

Comment: by "prompt" i mean that when the addItem event is fired on the sent items folder it asks the user if they would like to save the email. Hence the email triggers the event after it has gone through the outbox and into Sent Items. If the user says "yes", that they would like to save the email then the main form opens with the reference to the email that fired off the event in the first place.

Comment: Ok, So how is the email referenced in you main form ? is your "Main" form changeing the email in any way so that is need to be saved. You can check the isSaved property. It might be an idea to post the code. As it just sounds like an order thing or you are making the email dirty in some way.

Comment: hey, thanks for your reply and sorry it has taken so long to get back to you. I have edited the question above to include code.

the markAsProfiled function is what changes the subject of the email and then saves it and as mentioned it does so after confirmation that the email has been "Profiled". if i move that function to run prior to the myIem.SaveAs it works fine!

Answer (score 1):

if this is still relevant to you: You could use a self-defined column in which you could write wether the saving was successfull or not.

Example code:

```
 mail.UserProperties.Add("Profiled", Outlook.OlUserPropertyType.olText, true);
 mail.UserProperties["Profiled"].Value = "Yes";
 mail.Save();
```

The only disadvantage is that you've to add the field to the displayed columns in Outlook. (maybe that can be done programmatically)

About why your method doesn't work: I could imagine that Outlook doesn't like it when you change the subject of an email after it was sent.